# Visual Studio Code: текстовые сниппеты не предлагаются в комментариях /* */

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, сниппет

Работаю в Visual Studio Code 1.12.1

Создал свои собственные сниппеты для js. Если пользоваться ими для написания кода, то они корректно работают (набираешь префикс и в выпадающем списке IntelliSense присутствует сниппет).
Однако если писать внутри комментариев **/* */** , то сниппеты не работают.

Кто-то знает, как заставить сниппеты работать внутри комментариев?

Решаемая задача: я пишу документацию, она реализована следующим образом: есть набор `*.js`-файлов , в комментариях собственно идет текст документации (имя функции - возможные значения - примеры - и т.д.). Backend-генератор потом собирает их этих файлов красивую документацию на сайте.

Тело сниппета:

```json
"triggered": {
    "prefix": "tri",
    "body": "triggered",
    "description": "for 'event TRIGGERED'"
},
```

Comment: В сниппете не указывается контекст применения?

Comment: Нет, контекст не указывается. Тело сниппета: `"triggered": {
        "prefix": "tri",
        "body": "triggered",
        "description": "for 'event TRIGGERED'"
    },`

Comment: на всякий случай: а какую задачу вы решаете, зачем сниппеты в комментариях?

Comment: я пишу документацию , она реализована следующим образом: есть набор *.js-файлов , в комментариях собственно идет текст документации (имя функции - возможные значения - примеры - и т.д.). Backend-генератор потом собирает их этих файлов красивую документацию на сайте.

Comment: Вижу, что в Atom можно указывать контекст (scope) для сниппета. Попробуйте в нём, он похож на VSC, и, по моему субъективному мнению, Atom гораздо лучше.

Comment: Благодарю за совет! Придется пробовать :)

Comment: Есть плагин называется document this очень удобно оставлять комментарии к функциям (методам). Плагин сам смотрит параметры и возвращаемое значение и оформляет это в коментарии.

Comment: Привет мне из прошлого :) Решение внезапное: в настройках есть **editor.quickSuggestions**. Надо выставить comments: true и тогда intellisense будет предлагать варианты из сниппетов при написании в комментах. <br/>  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": true,
        "strings": false
    }

Answer (score 0):

Для ищущих, есть два варианта

1. В `setting.json` настроить.

```json
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "on", 
        "strings": "off"
    }
```

2. <kbd>F1</kbd> -> `Insert Snippet` -> и выбрать нужный